# Can't open a page in Selenium with Chrome (Python), can open it manually in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to open the following page in chrome with selenium in python. it doesn't open when i try to open it with the 'driver.get(url)' command. but it opens if I put the link into Chrome (the same window that didn't work a second ago with 'driver.get(url)' command) manually and press enter. any idea why?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('//api.netlook.com/service/widgets/vhtell/content.jsp?id=coggindelandford-d&clientId=DDCGROUPSITES&dealer=coggindelandfordfd&vin=3FADP4BJ7KM126162&tabs=PHOTO&tabs=VIDEOTELL&tabs=SPINTELL&useTabIcons=true&refererHost=www.coggindelandford.com&refererUrl=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.coggindelandford.com%252Fnew%252FFord%252F2019-Ford-Fiesta-in%252BOrlando-25f691af0a0e0aea042ff3df80ee344f.htm%253FsearchDepth%253D81%253A172')
```

Comment: try a valid url

Comment: Protocol is missing. Please provide the correct protocol at the beginning of url like https